# Are there reliable VNC client to access from Windows 10 connecting to macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, windows, software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I want to remote access my MacBook Pro running Sierra from my Windows 10 PC.

I followed [these steps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25556?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) from the Apple site but it does not work.

Both RealVNC and the VNC app for the Chrome browser result in connection timeout errors. Both computers are on the same network and I have tried providing port 5900 with no success.

Any to make these more reliable or change software to achieve a solid connection?

Comment: Did you enable screen sharing on your Mac?  See this image:  https://binged.it/2tl9j3y

Comment: I can't enable Screen sharing if Remote Management is enabled. It's one or the other and I've tried both.

Comment: Getting VNC 'working' from Windows is incredible painful and annoying.  Last time I got it 'working' it failed again after a point release, and even when it was 'working' there was lag, pixelation, and various quirks. Apple has clearly mangled VNC to the point where its not even close to a stock *nix configuration.  You're probably better off pursuing a different desktop sharing method from Windows to macOS.  Sorry this isn't too helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try TeamViewer. It has an ID for your computer that's tied to your account and can be used to control your computer from anywhere. I've used it to control OSX from Windows 10 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The native Mac OS VNC server is wonky. I have had success using TightVNC to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself from Windows to Mac, but I have used [Jump Desktop](https://www.jumpdesktop.com) to successfully connect from iOS to Mac and Mac to Mac… and they have a Windows client, so maybe that's worth checking out?

Note that there is a free [Jump Desktop Connect](https://jumpdesktop.com/connect/) utility which you should setup on the Mac for easier connections.